# Change Opacity of Flutter Hints in Vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the opacity of the flutter hints in VsCode?
(I'd like to make them slightly dimmer than actual comments)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as `dart.closingLabels`. You can provide any color as you like.

Go to your VS Code setting and open `settins.json`.

[image]

Now provide color on

```json
{  ....
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       ...
        "dart.closingLabels": "#08ff94" // change this
    },
}
```

[image]

I am doing only for current project, to reflect on all project stay on `User` instead of `WorkSpace`

> Workflow

[image]